# Android Gradle Plugin 7.2 ignores added proguard file in Android App build process

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

I have a `Gradle` plugin I wrote for an Android app project. Amongst other things - this plugin adds a custom `ProGuard` rules file to all ApplicationVariants being built.

the has worked fine until Android Gradle plugin `7.2` was introduced. Since I started using AGP 7.2 to compile my app - the ProGuard file that's added by the plugin **is ignored**.

`Code`:

```kotlin
    project.android.buildTypes[<variant.buildType.name>].proguardFile = new File(<custom Proguard rules file path>)
```

This worked in AGP <= 7.0 without any problems. There are no exceptions in the logs of the build process.

**I tried another approach and got the same results :**
I tried to add a ProGuard file with a script (not using a plugin at all) - but the results were the same - **this file is ignored**.
This is the code I added in `build.gradle` :

```
afterEvaluate {
    for (def buildType : project.android.buildTypes) {
       buildType.proguardFile file(< full path>)
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no Gradle plugin - while the said functionality can be configured by default. See https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.2/classes

Comment: What do you mean there is no Gradle plugin? I'm not sure I understand.
anyway, in AGP 7.2 setting this in the defaults works but setting it in a script does not. I'll clarify it in the question's description.

Comment: The statement "I have a Gradle plugin" doesn't suffice to reproduce the issue. Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ... `afterEvalute`  might be too late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Groovy the value can be set for `android.defaultConfig`:

```
// this sets one file
android.defaultConfig { config ->
    proguardFile new File("../general.pro")
}

// this adds an additional file
android.defaultConfig { config ->
    proguardFiles.add(new File("../general.pro"))
}

// proof of concept
android.buildTypes { buildType ->
    println buildType
}
```

This happens before `:prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel`, which means early on.